# "Первое" и "Второе" - что это за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> "Первое. Прочитайте пособие. Второе. Сделайте задание..."

Как трактовать слова "Первое" и "Второе" с точки зрения синтаксиса, если они оформлены как предложение? Можно ли рассматривать эти случаи как назывные предложения?

Comment: Это же цифры. Или вы можете привести реальный пример, где используются именно слова?